# trying to make <li> text apear in front of <li> containers' borders with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, menu, border, css

I've made a horizontal menu using a list. I'm trying to get each `<li>` to appear as a horizontal rectangle with wedges snipped out of its sides - `snip> <snip` - and text centered horizontally and vertically.

I thought I could accomplish this by giving the `<li>`'s a line-height of 0, making the borders thick, and making the right and left border transparent, but it behaves like there's still .4em of line height or something.

A note about the attached code: I have nothing resembling a formal education, so I expect there to be some serious holes in my method and code. I am absolutely willing to take all input in the interest of making my code semantic, clean, and simple.

Thanks for your help!

```
#CAPMenu li  
{
    float:left;
    width:95px;
    border-top: 20px solid #4672A3;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #4672A3;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    line-height:0em;
}

<div id="CAPMenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Idea</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Concept</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Feasability</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Scale Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Launch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Post Launch</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `height:0` instead of `line-height:0em;`?

Comment: jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5JGD/ @Pete: I don't think a "formal education" would help you with this actually. This isn't the sort of thing they would teach, unless perhaps you went to an art/design school. Otherwise, this wouldn't be considered sciencey enough to teach.

Comment: consider using a shorthand approach to your border declarations: `border-color: #4672A3 transparent; border-style: solid; border-width: 10px`

Comment: @ zzzzBov: Thanks for the shorthand tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding "height: 0" gives me some wedges:

[image]

Comment: meagar and ordnungswidrig, that's the nail on the head!

Thanks!